# Programmatically setting ImageView resource not working

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to implement a feature where the user can select an image file from storage and that image gets displayed in a thumbnail-sized ImageView.

The file picking part seems to be correct:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_ATTACHMENT_RESULT); 

//...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GET_ATTACHMENT_RESULT){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            // Anything TODO here?
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            addTimeFragment.onImageUrlReceived(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

The returning Uri appears to be a content Uri and has some path like:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A14702
```

Calling uri.getPath() returns:

```
/document/image:14702
```

I have tried many different solutions found on numerous Stack Overflow posts involving Picasso (ideal solution), creating Bitmaps from various methods, setting the ImageView Uri, etc...

**No Programmatic Method of Setting the ImageView Resource Works- even on PNGs located in my drawables.** I can only successfully set the `android:src` in the XML.

Sanity Check:

- The ImageView is visible, is constrained correctly, and has appropriate height and width.
- I can set a source image in the xml and it appears. I also set the background color to make sure it's on screen. Everything is fine in XML.
- I can also successfully programmatically set the ImageView background color so I know I am referencing the correct ImageView in code.

XML:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/time_entry_spacer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/camera_bg"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:background="#220000FF"/>
```

Assigning the ImageView:

```java
//attachThumbnail is my ImageView
attachThumbnail = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
attachThumbnail.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));  // This works as a sanity check
```

Various failures with the onImageUrlReceived Method:

```java
public void onImageUrlReceived(Uri uri){
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "URI: " + uri.toString());
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "URI: " + uri.getPath());

// Even loading a known drawable fails
// Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.calendar).fit().error(R.drawable.error).into(attachThumbnail);


// Picasso.with(context).load(uri).fit().error(R.drawable.error).into(attachThumbnail);


// Picasso.with(context).load(uri.getPath()).fit().error(R.drawable.error).into(attachThumbnail);


//        File imgFile = new  File(url);
//        if(imgFile.exists()){
//            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
//
//            attachThumbnail.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
//        }


//        attachThumbnail.setImageURI(uri);


//        Bitmap bitmap = null;
//        try {
//            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        attachThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


//        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
//        attachThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);


// See DownloadImage AsyncTask below
//        new DownloadImage(attachThumbnail).execute(uri.getPath());


// InputStream with scaling
//        try {
//            InputStream ims = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
//            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
//            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 50, 50, false);
//            attachThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b2);
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }


// InputStream without Scaling
//        Bitmap bitmap = null;
//        try {
//            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        attachThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Any other thoughts or insights here are ***greatly*** appreciated. I am definitely beating my head against a wall on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems `onImageUrlReceived(url)` is never called?

Comment: @TaQuangTu Thanks for the comment. It's called in ```onActivityResult()```.  The onImageUrlReceived() method resides within a Fragment.

Comment: did you try with `new DownloadImage(attachThumbnail).execute(uri.getPath());` and get undesired result?

Comment: I did try that. I figured it out. I am going to leave an answer below for anyone else who runs into this. Thanks for your effort @TaQuangTu

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

Because my ImageView was residing within a Fragment and not directly in the Activity, I was calling `onImageUrlReceived(Uri uri)` *before* `onResume()` was being called on my Fragment. `onActivityResult` is called before the Fragment resumes. As a result, the ImageView was being set correctly, but then a split second later, I was reassigning the ImageView when onResume was called so it would look like nothing was done.

As a result, I am now storing the Uri as a Fragment member and in `onResume()`:

````java
attachThumbnail = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

if (userAttachmentUri != null){
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(userAttachmentUri).fit().into(attachThumbnail);
}```
````